# Добавление/удаление кнопок телеграмм бота через телеграмм

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, бот

Коллеги, пишу бота телеграмм, который будет агрегатором тематик для пабликов.

Есть задача сделать так, чтобы админ мог сам делать корректировки и вставлять/удалять кнопки(тематики) через чат-админку телеги.

Как можно реализовать добавление кнопок больше заданного количества, а также их удаление админом.

Comment: как у вас реализована клавиатура?

Comment: @Александр клавиатура реализована через массив функцией. 




`keyboard = telebotapi.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
def build_menu(keyboard):
    keyboard.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="key1", callback_data="key1"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="key2", callback_data="key2"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="key3", callback_data="key3")
    )
 return keyboard`



Где текст = переменной из бд, которую админ может задать (она записывается - перезаписывается), но количество заданных кнопок изменить нельзя, вот и ломаю голову)